# Javascript passing argument to function that is a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, callback

I have a function that accepts an argument called buttonID that I need to get passed to multiple other functions. When the link is clicked the ID is passed along.

```
 <a href="#" class="theme_btn" id="check-user" onClick="javascript:checkUser(this.id);">User Check</a>
```

My function is

```
function checkUser(buttonID) { 
 //do some stuff
 var data = {};
 data.callback = getUserInfo;
 data.username = uname;
 data.level = lvl;
 checkLevel(data);
 }
```

The problem I am having is that I am unable to pass buttonID to the callback function, getUserInfo.

I have tried getUserInfo(buttonID) but it does not function correctly. Should I be using the following syntax of getUserInfo({buttonID]) ?

In short, I need the value of buttonID to be passed from function to function and I believe it's the syntax that is holding me back. Any ideas or suggestions on what I could try differently?

Comment: Add `data.buttonId = buttonID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind`:

```
function checkUser(buttonID) { 
 //do some stuff
 var data = {};
 data.callback = getUserInfo.bind(null, buttonID);
 data.username = uname;
 data.level = lvl;
 checkLevel(data);
}
```

more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an anonymous function:

```
data.callback = function(){getUserInfo(buttonID)}
```

With the JavaScript ES6 syntax, a bit shorter:

```
data.callback = _=>{getUserInfo(buttonID)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var buttonIDGlobal;

function checkUser(buttonID) { 

 buttonIDGlobal = buttonID;
 //do some stuff
 var data = {};
 data.callback = getUserInfo;
 data.username = uname;
 data.level = lvl;
 checkLevel(data);
 }
```

```html
You can simple define a global variable and assign the button ID to that variable. 


Now "buttonIDGlobal" is accessible in "getUserInfo()" function.`enter code here`
```